# MongoDB - findAndModify with WriteConcern

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Is it possible to specify a WriteConcern in findAndModify operation? If not, what is the default WriteConcern?

BTW, I'm using the java driver.

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB Java Driver is a Wrapper to access the MongoDB shell commands from inside of your java code. [`DBCollection#findAndModify`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) does not provide a flag to force a `WriteConcern` for a single operation. So this Operation uses the default setting of the `mongod` instance it is writing to.

Comment: Where can I setup that default setting of the mongod? This limitation is in the mongo server thus apply to all mongo drivers (see [SERVER-6568](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6558)).

Answer (score 0):

From Mongodb 3.0 DOCS:

You cannot specify a write concern to findAndModify to override the default write concern whereas, starting in MongoDB 2.6, you can specify a write concern to the update() method.